# Is it possible to Populate a listbox with a non-contiguous named range?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a single column list box, which I want populated by table names that are on one worksheet. I've Ctrl clicked all the names and named them, however when I enter the range name into the properties table of the userform, they don't show up. What am I doing wrongly?

I would also state that I want to avoid creating a separate list on another worksheet.

What is intriguing is the fact that when you copy non contiguous data and paste it, it pastes contiguously. How does excel do this? I've recorded the macro and it's just 'activesheet.paste'. Can you paste into an array? ...to then use the array as the list, without having to create another list?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
arrayname = rangename.value 'set named range to array
sheet1.listbox1.list = arrayname 'set array to listbox values
```